# Android Canvas vs. GLSurfaceView for Drag/Drop operations

Tags: android, opengl-es, canvas, drag-and-drop

I am building aprogram that needs to do drag/drop operations of images.  Now on a Canvas it is quite easy, and I might chose this.  However, I am also interested in using GLSurface View??  Now what I am seeing in examples is either a drag/drop tutorial on Canvas or drawing on GLSurface view.  I am wondering if handling touch events is more complicated with GLSurface view?  Is it possible to handle touch events with GLSurfaceView.  Also why would one chose GLSurface view for rendering images vs. a Canvas?  How does one chose between Canvas vs. GLSurfaceView?

Answer (score 1):

It's really just a choice between two APIs.

Canvas:

- knows about common Android framework classes like Bitmap
- many convenient functions
- can draw into bitmaps for saving to the SDCard

GLSurfaceView:

- good for using the tried-and-true OpenGL API
- designed for redrawing rapidly at a certain framerate
- 3D drawing

These are just a few aspects of the debate. I don't think either of them has the upper hand on event processing. I'd say that it makes more sense to use Canvas if you are working primarily with the Android SDK, whereas GLSurfaceView is an especially good option for apps using the OpenGL APIs via the NDK.

Comment: Ok. Well I am primarily working with Android SDK, just wondering if I would get some benifit for the rendering of the images as textures in OpenGL?  Or should I just draw to canvas.  I want to do things like rotate, and scale the images.  Make the image start from an invisible . to a full scale image etc.  I know I can do this with Canvas, but would I get any benifit to doing it in GL?

Comment: I don't think so. It would just make it more complicated in my opinion.